# Sending a parameter from activity1 to Activity2

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android application i want to send the value of EditText from an Activity1 to Activity2 to be used there  ..What can i do please??

//This is my first Activity

```
public class registrer extends Activity {
   EditText ET_USER_NAME,ET_USER_PASS,ET_USER_CONFIRM;
Button btsuivant;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrer);

    ET_USER_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CreerCV3.class);
    intent.putExtra("Key1", ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString());
  }}
```

// the CreerCV3

```
public class CreerCV3 extends Activity {

String user_name,user_pass,user_confirm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_creer_cv3);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String s=intent.getStringExtra("Key1");
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ob);
    t.setText(s);
     }}
```

//xml of the textviex

```
    android:id="@+id/ob" />
```

//xml of the editText (regiter)

seems like everthing is ok but when i run the app there is no text displayed.....

Comment: just get that editText value and pass it to your second activity using `Intent`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In First Activity you can do like below...

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( FirstAcvity.this, SecondActivity.class ); 
intent.putExtra ( "TextBox", editText.getText().toString() );
startActivity(intent);
```

In second activity, use following...

```
Intent i = getIntent(); 
String text = i.getStringExtra ( "TextBox","" );
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: If it help you, can you Up vote it or you can accept my answer. If it is very very helpful, you can do both of it.@OumaymaJaziri

Comment: Please when i did like this i tried to display the value of the 'new user_name' in the second activity !Nothing is happend

Comment: Do you have TextView in second activity? If so, just do like below.

`TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.second_activity_textview_id);
tv.setText(text);`

Where **text** is a String variable in above my answer.

Comment: i did this but nothing was displayed please check my code i will edit my question

Comment: Just add your whole code with both **XML** and **JAVA** files.@OumaymaJaziri

Comment: You forgot to write `startActivity(intent);`@OumaymaJaziri

Comment: the problem that when i add startActivity The register activity is not shown again .. but the CreerCV3 actiivty is shown without displaying the value of the editText.. i dont understand the issue!!

Comment: Do like below@OumaymaJaziri

Add below lines to `onCreate()` method...

 `btsuivant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
 btsuivant.setOnClickListener(this);`
 
Add this `implements View.OnClickListener` after `extends Activity` AND

Add below method after `onCreate(){}`

 `@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_id:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreerCV3.class);
                intent.putExtra("Key1", ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }`

Comment: the problem is : when i click at the button bt_suivant i pass to a second activity(CreerCV2) where i enter the employee's information then i click at a second button (Suivant) to take me to the third activity (CreerCV3) in that activity i add other informations and press button Register .... To register the employee 's information (means the information that was coming from activity Resgister&CreerCV2& CreerCV3) i hope that my idea is clear and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Go to below link where I have put all the details....[link is here](http://pastebin.com/SnjGAFa3)..@OumaymaJaziri

Comment: What are you trying to achieve basically? If you want to Register a user, you can simply ask user for his/her information in **First** activity. You do not need **Second** and **Third** activity.@OumaymaJaziri

Comment: You can use [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) for putting you screen shots. You can send me your project and tell me you requirement on [Wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/). I will sort it out.@OumaymaJaziri

Comment: If I have helped you. Please, up vote my answer.@OumaymaJaziri

Answer (score 1):

You can use intent and `putextra()` in your first activity like below:

in activity one:

```
EditText editText;
editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);

Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("key",editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

in activity two:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String s=intent.getStringExtra("key");

Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the "Build your first app" section of android developers site? The task you are asking about is quite well explained there!

from
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

```
//build you intent to start the activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
//take the text from your edittext
String message = yourEditText.getText().toString();
//add that text as an extra to the activity
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
//start the Activity
startActivity(intent);
```

that's all!!